# How to fix: TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null on my code?

Tags: javascript, string, substring, uppercase

I was trying to make a single word with all the uppercase letters of a string and it gives me this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null

I realized that is because between `join()` I have no elements between quotes. If I leave it empty I get the commas.

```
var letters = "Sos oli Un Maraca Amigo";

function findMessage(data) {
  var hola = data.match(/[A-Z]+/g).join("");
  console.log(hola);
}

findMessage(letters)
```

My expected output for that example is: `SUMA`

Comment: The error means that `data.match()` is returning `null`

Comment: Also the code works fine as posted.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5qbmLe04/1/ Works fine

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have tested it on Console and It Did wok, but it doesn't on checkIO.org.

Answer (score 1):

you need a null check of some kind:

```
var hola = (data.match(/[A-Z]+/g) || []).join("");
```

this will yield an empty string in the event of no match.

Comment: I used to think if there is no match, it gonna return ''[]'', I was wrong